Avoid duplicated CSS/JS inside Jinja2 macro?
How does one avoid duplicated CSS/JS inside a Jinja2 macro?
So lets say I have a Jinja2 macro which contains a CSS <style> and JS <script> tag like this:
{% macro render_test(eleID) %}
    <style> .testEle {color: red;} </style>

    <div class="testEle" id="{{ eleID }}"></div>

    <script> function foo() {} </script>
{% endmacro %}

This will duplicate the <style> and <script> for every call to the macro on the site.
I tried adding an additional parameter e.g. add_css_js and according if statements, but this doesn't seem clean and correct.
So how can one avoid this? Or whats the correct way to handle this?

I think the correct way would be to make another macro to import the styles and scripts for this macro.
